# Extracting strings from an input field using regular expressions and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, expression, match

I am trying to match a string in an input field using a regular expression `/[1-9][a-zA-Z]/` and insert it into a `<p>` tag using jQuery.

I modified [this](http://api.jquery.com/val/) example from the jQuery API docs to include the following `if` statement. When I type '1A' in the input field it works, however I want to exclude the rest of the string so that the `<p>` only includes the matched string portion.

```
    $("input").keyup(function () {

            if($(this).val().match(/[1-9][a-zA-Z]/)){
               var value = $(this).val();
            };

      $("p").text(value);
    }).keyup();
```

Did I explain that clearly? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are doing in the above code is that if the value of the input field matches the regular expression, you assign its value to `<p>` tag. Since, you want to assign the matched string to the `<p>` tag, you should do:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
        var match = $(this).val().match(/[1-9][a-zA-Z]/);
        if(match){
           var value = match[0]; // Your problem was here
        };

  $("p").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

The `match` method of a `String` returns an array containing the match if it passed or `undefined` if the match failed.

Comment: Thanks this is spot on, and a much simpler solution than I had in mind.